# How to successfully transfer one .blend to another computer and keep everything intact?

Tags: packed-data

Okay, here's what's going on. I have one of my biggest animation projects yet that I will be sending to another computer to render. *I have packed the image textures* so as to make sure that they will not be lost. Now, the project contains audio files in the VSE (music and sound effects) and it also contains an image sequence. These are the ones I'm concerned about. It is my understanding that Blender does not pack audio files and image sequences, correct?

If that is correct, then that means moving the .blend to another computer will result in lost audio and a lost image sequence. Is there any way to keep everything in the .blend file, even if it means blowing up the file size?

This problem may be resulting from messy organization on my part. Consolidating everything into one folder at this point (in order to make the paths relative and therefore move the entire folder with no issues) would take a while and become tedious quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Video files and image sequences are not packed as part of the blend file.

Why? because they would create an impractically large file.

No video editing program stores the media and the projects on a single file.

The way you transfer the project is you bring along all of the files that are linked to the project. If you want a single file to transport/upload, then zip the folder with all the elements and the project.

But it is more practical to put your files in an external drive and plug it in to to the new computer and re-link.

Comment: My mistake. Audio files can be packed. I'll put the image sequence with the blend and I think that will do it. If you don't mind, could you edit the second line of your answer? Thank you!